# Update Apollo Client object on runtime on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am working on a project where I am using a Rest API for data (token) to be passed on to the GraphQL API later after authentication.
The whole app is wrapped in an ApolloProvider object like the example below.

```
const Client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: [Broker Address],
        headers: {
            authorization: `[Bearer token to be retrieved using a Rest API]`,
         }
    }),
    cache: memoryCache
})
```

Wrapper code:

```
<ApolloProvider client={Client}>
    <AppNavigator />      
</ApolloProvider>
```

But since I am retrieving the graphql token after authentication from the Rest API, I won't be able to pass the data at initialisation.

The obvious (i might be wrong since I am really new to JS and RN) alternative is to have two separate navigators (one for the Rest auth flow, and the other for the GraphQL flow) and only to wrap the GraphQL based navigator with ApolloProvider.

But just wanted to check if there is a way to dynamically update the HttpLink or the ApolloClient object on the ApolloProvider wrapper later during runtime?

Comment: This question appears a little vague to me, but it seems to me that if you simply didn't have `const` there, you should be able to initialize your `Client = null` and then assign it after you have a REST response.

Comment: Hi @IanMacDonald, thanks for your suggestion. What I was meaning is that is there a way to update the `client` property of `ApolloProvider` on a later time (runtime) from a component which is a part of  the `AppNavigator` stack. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: @metpb did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Jayesh This should help. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context.html